# Java: How do I edit a JFrame using variables?

Tags: java, list, arraylist, jframe

I am fairly new to Java programming and I can't figure out why this code always produces a blank JFrame:

mainClass.java:

```
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class mainClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        drawing d = new drawing();

        d.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        d.setSize(1000, 1000);
        d.setTitle("Test Game");
        d.setVisible(true);
        d.repaint();
        d.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
                d.repaint();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

drawing.java:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class drawing extends JFrame implements MouseListener{
    public List<units> p1 = new ArrayList<units>();
    public List<units> p2 = new ArrayList<units>();
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        for(units u : p1) {
            g.setColor(new Color(0,0,255));
            g.drawRect(u.unitX-1, u.unitY-1, u.unitX+1, u.unitY+1);
        }
    }
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
        int x = e.getX();
        int y = e.getY();
        p1.add(new units(x,y));

        boolean tryPrint = true;

        if(p1.size()==10 && tryPrint) {
            for(units u : p1) {
                System.out.println(u.unitX + "," + u.unitY);
            }

            tryPrint = false;
        }

        frame.repaint();
    }

    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {}
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {}
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {}
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {}
}
```

units.java:

```
public class units {
    int unitX;
    int unitY;
    units(int x, int y) {
        unitX = x;
        unitY = y;
    }
}
```

Sorry for the wordy code. I believe the issue lies somewhere in my handling of the variables or classes. Any help is appreciated.

Also, this code is edited so that may be the reason some comments don't make sense.

Comment: There is a disconnection between `mainClass` and `drawing`, in that each is creating a new instance of each - so they are not sharing the same information

Comment: I think your design is wrong.  Instead of `mainClass` managing the `MouseListener` and points, `drawing` should be

Comment: You can't just create a **new** instance of mainClass (`mainClass m = new mainClass();`) and expect it to interact with the one created earlier during start up. Moreover, `p1` and `p2` lists should belong only to your new JComponent class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that the issue was in my inclusion of the drawing class into a JFrame and where to locate that JFrame. My final, solved code follows:

mainClass.java:

```
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class mainClass {
    private static int x, y;
    private static drawing d = new drawing();
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Mouse");
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(1000, 1000);
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.add(d);
        d.addMouseListener(new AL());
    }
    static class AL extends MouseAdapter{
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
            x = e.getX();
            y = e.getY();
            d.draw(x,y);
        }
    }
}
```

drawing.java:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class drawing extends JPanel {
    public void draw(int x, int y) {
        p1.add(new ArrayList<Integer>());
        p1.get(p1.size()-1).add(x);
        p1.get(p1.size()-1).add(y);
        repaint();
    }
    public List<List<Integer>> p1 = new ArrayList<List<Integer>>(); 
    public List<List<Integer>> p2 = new ArrayList<List<Integer>>();
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        for(List<Integer> u : p1) {
            g.setColor(new Color(0,0,255));
            g.fillRect(u.get(0)-1, u.get(1)-1, 3, 3);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First think I advise you to use more cohesive classes. Besides that I would like to say you need to override JFrame's paint method instead of creating a new class for it, see an example here: http://www.gailer-net.de/tutorials/java3/Notes/chap56/ch56_8.html.

I hope you conclude your application.

Regards,

-Rod

Comment: I am now experiencing an issue where the frame is just empty, this may be because I switched the MouseEvent and the points into the drawing class. Do you know why this may be happening?

Comment: Please @Bug put your new code here, then we can evaluate what is going on.

Comment: Also, it would be nice if you showed the solution in code, thank you